# error loading module: ... undefined symbol: luaL_register

Tags: lua, zerobrane

```
    ZeroBrain Studio (ZBS): error loading module 'rds.parser' from file '/opt/zbstudio/bin/linux/x64/clibs53/rds/parser.so':
        /opt/zbstudio/bin/linux/x64/clibs53/rds/parser.so: undefined symbol: luaL_register
    stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        lua/system/pgsql.lua:11: in main chunk
```

I need to add to my ZeroBrane Studio project  the external C++ module which I got from let's say from some external resource https://github.com/openresty/lua-rds-parser

I'm using lua 5.3 , ZeroBrane Studio on ubuntu 19.04.

I complied the library `lua-rds-parser` mentioned above and received the parser.so , simply via 
        `sudo make` - command launched into unzipped directory.
I copied the `parser.so` to the directory `/opt/zbstudio/bin/linux/x64/clibs53/rds/parser.so` from there the `ZeroBrane` Studio attempt to find it when launched the my `hello.lua` - file  where I wrote:

```
    local parser = require("rds.parser")
```

Done as described in http://webserver2.tecgraf.pucrio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/install.html.

However the error message is as follows:
   undefined symbol: luaL_register

Comment: Lua version mismatch?

Comment: from the makefile you say you used: "LUA_VERSION =   5.1"

Answer (score 2):

As was already indicated in the comments, you have likely compiled `rds.parser` against Lua 5.1 library (which provides `luaL_register`), but are trying to load it into Lua 5.3, which doesn't provide this function, as it has been deprecated. You need to re-compile `rds.parser` against Lua 5.3, so it can be loaded by Lua 5.3 interpreter.